# Hide status bar in iOS from PageRenderer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to hide a status bar in a PageRenderer?

I tried setting these in `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

And then overriding `PrefersStatusBarHidden` in the `PageRenderer` as

```
public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden()
{
   return true;
}
```

If I set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in `Info.plist` to `false`, it is hidden on all pages.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your app use a `NavigationPage`? If the `UIViewController` created by the PageRenderer is embedded in a `UINavigationController` then that `UINavigationController` may not be using your `PrefersStatusBarHidden`. Can you very that your `PrefersStatusBarHidden` is called?

Comment: Yes, it is using a NavigationPage. No, `PrefersStatusBarHidden` is not being called :(

Comment: My guess is that your `UINavigationController` isn't forwarding `PrefersStatusBarHidden` - I'd try to use a custom class that subclasses `UINavigationController` and override `PrefersStatusBarHidden`, it can just do something simple like call `return TopViewController.PrefersStatusBarHidden();`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dylan :D 
It worked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a custom UINavigationController instead of the system one, like this sample:

In AppDelegate.cs:

```
UINavigationController navController;
    UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        navController = new UINavigationController (new TestViewCtonroller ());

        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        window.RootViewController = navController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
```

MyNavigationController.cs:

```
public class MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public MyNavigationController (UIViewController rootController) : base(rootController)
    {
    }

    public override UIViewController ChildViewControllerForStatusBarHidden ()
    {
        return TopViewController;
    }

    public override UIViewController ChildViewControllerForStatusBarStyle ()
    {
        return TopViewController;
    }
}
```

TestViewCtonroller.cs:

```
public class TestViewCtonroller : UIViewController
{
    public TestViewCtonroller ()
    {
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }

    public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle ()
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
    }

    public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden ()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.